# Generic OR instead of AND <T extends Number | CharSequence>

Tags: java, android, generics, types, charsequence

Is it possible to generically parameterize a method accepting EITHER ClassA OR InterfaceB ?

**Does Not Compile Due to | Pseudocode**

```
public <T extends Number | CharSequence> void orDoer(T someData){ // ... }
```

i.e. instead of writing multiple method signatures, I would like this one method to accept either a Number or CharSequence as an argument

**Should Pass with a Number OR CharSequence argument**

```
orDoer(new Integer(6));
int somePrimitive = 4;
orDoer(somePrimitive);
orDoer("a string of chars");
```

Comment: What would you do inside that method that cannot be done with two separate methods that accept `Number` or `CharSequence` respectively and then delegate to a third, private method to do the work?

Comment: I agree the gains are insubstantial if I am dealing with two types, but it would seem a nice concise way to delegate more parameter types (that do not share a usable supertype)

Comment: You should check out [Ceylon](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.1/introduction/)'s union types. ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you **really** want to do that, you'll need to wrap youur accepted classes inside a custom class of your own. In your example case, probably something like:

```
public class OrDoerElement {
    private final Number numberValue;
    private final CharSequence charSequenceValue;

    private OrDoerElement(Number number, CharSequence charSequence) {
        this.numberValue = number;
        this.charSequenceValue = charSequence;
    }

    public static OrDoerElement fromCharSequence(CharSequence value) {
        return new OrDoerElement(null, value);
    }

    public static OrDoerElement fromNumber(Number value) {
        return new OrDoerElement(value, null);
    }
}
```

And your `orDoer` method becomes:

```
public void orDoer(OrDoerElement someData) { .... }
```

Then you can build one of those and use in your method using either:

```
orDoer(OrDoerElement.fromCharSequence("a string of chars"));
orDoer(OrDoerElement.fromNumber(new Integer(6)));
```

But honestly, that sounds a bit too complex and too much work just to be able to call a method with different parameter types. Are you sure you can't achieve the same using two methods, and a third method for the common logic?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I realize now i didnt explain my use-case properly - I was looking for something very similar to `T extends ClassA | InterfaceB` because i wanted the caller of my method to be able to pass in their type as-is (Integer or String etc directly). That is, to provide a `store(T data)` method, which would accept all kinds of types having the characteristic of being fully re-constructable from .toString() and a standard single-parameter instantiation (Number, CharSequence, Date and many more persistable types).

Comment: i.e. another way I could have asked the question is why is there no shared type - before Object - for Number, CharSequence and other native types, which would characterise them as those Uniconstructables or whatever you would want to call them .. (hope it makes sense)

Comment: Yes, I understand, this kind of super-super class would indeed prove useful in some cases

Answer (score 1):

Is using an anonymous abstract class an option for you? When I need type safe parameters or return types, I use some variant of the code below. That being said, I agree with the other comments here, and am curious what benefit you really derive when you're enforcing a type safety for a group of objects that don't have all that much in common.

```
public abstract class Doer<T> {

  public void do(T obj) {
    // do some stuff. 
  }

}

// calling method

new Doer<Number>(){}.do(new Integer(5));
```

Comment: Thanks, please see the clarification under Guillaume's post.

Answer (score 1):

For the original question:

```
public void orDoer(Object someData){
    assert someData instanceof Number || someData instanceof CharSequence;

    // ...
}
```

In your more specific case, the `assert` statement should just use introspection to clarify if the object has the specifics you want, i.e. check for a constructor from String, probe to create a new instance of the object from the `toString()` result of the incoming object, and compare both for equality:

```
public void orDoer(Object someData) {
    assert isUniconstructable(someData);
}

public static boolean isUniconstructable(Object object) {
    try {
        return object.equals(object.getClass().getConstructor(String.class)
            .newInstance(object.toString()));
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException
            | NoSuchMethodException| RuntimeException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

(Because of the exceptions that may be thrown, we need to wrap the assert test into its own function.)

Be aware that introspection *may* break due to Android’s ProGuard code compression which rewrites the class names, and instead of `YourClass` just a Class, i.e. `Q`, is stored in the database, and when you want to restore it with a later version of your app which has more classes, class `Q` is something different then. See the ProGuard website for more information on this; I just wanted to notify that you should be aware of this when using introspection on Android.