# How to limit generic class parameter to certain classes

Tags: java, generics

In my generic class I need to restrict type parameter to `Integer` **OR** `String`. Is there a way to achieve this? I cannot use `T extends SomeClass` to limit types, because common parent is just Object...

**update**

```
public abstract class MyClass<T>{

    private T value;

    public T getValue(){
        return value;
    }
}
```

I'd like the `value` type to be a `String` or an `Integer` and I need to use the same method to get it (not `getIntValue()` + `getStringValue()` )

[This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) doesn't seem to help...

Comment: See this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330370/generic-or-instead-of-and-t-extends-number-charsequence

Answer (score 3):

If I were you, I would **overload** two methods:

```
public void withInteger(Integer param) { .. }

public void withString(String param) { .. }
```

Note that there's no reason to use something like `T extends String`, because **both** `String` and `Integer` are `final` and can't be subclassed.

Comment: Then if I were you, I were him as well?

Comment: Haha, and if I was him, I were you also :)

Comment: Only if the "if I were you"-relation was defined as transitive.

Answer (score 0):

Just made your class ctor private and pass through a factory method to create implementation; type restriction is not bounded to `MyClass` but via factory.

```
class MyClass<T> {
  private T value;

  MyClass(T value) { this.value = value; }
  public T getValue() { return value; }
}

class MyClassFactory {
  public final static MyClass<Integer> createInteger(Integer i) {
    return new MyClass<Integer>(i);
  }
}
```